# Is it possible in Scala to use isAssignableFrom with type parameters?

Tags: java, scala, traits, type-parameter

I am implementing a JAX-RS service in Scala using Jersey. I would to have a generic trait for Json provider, and I need to know if the requested Class is supported by my provider. In java is not possible to know the class of a type parameter at runtime because the type erasure. But it is possible to do in scala?

This code does not work:

```
trait JsonProvider[A] extends MessageBodyReader[A] with MessageBodyWriter[A] {

  final def isReadable(t : Class[_],
             genericType: Type,
             annotations: Array[Annotation],
             mediaType: MediaType): Boolean = {
    t.isAssignableFrom(classOf[A]) && mediaType == MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE
  }
}
```

Any suggestion? In Java the best method is to have a protected abstract method returning the class of A, in Scala too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is workaround for this. You can use `Manifest` type class. By using it, Scala compiler will make sure, that class information would be available at runtime. `Manifest` has `erasure` property - it's the class object for generic type.

You can use it for method's type parameters like this:

```
def printClass[T](implicit ev: Manifest[T]) =
  println(ev.erasure.getSimpleName)
```

or simlified:

```
def printClass1[T: Manifest] =
  println(manifest[T].erasure.getSimpleName)
```

You can also use it for classes or abstract classes:

```
class Printer[T: Manifest] {
  def printName = println(manifest[T].erasure.getSimpleName)
}
```

Unfortunately you can't use it for traits.

**Edit:** As workaround, you can define trait like this:

```
trait Printer[T] {
  def printName(implicit ev: Manifest[T]) =
    println(ev.erasure.getSimpleName)
}
```

Comment: Yes I just noted it is impossible to use for Trait because of the implicit constructor parameter.

Comment: If you need to, you can also put an abstract val for the manifest in a trait, like `trait Printer[T]{val ev:Manifest[T];...}` and override like `class Foo extends Printer[String] { override val ev=manifest[String]}`